# Compress Sass and include sourcemaps with gulp?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

Is possible to compress sass and include sourcemaps in the result? If I include `.pipe(cssnano())` it removes the sourcemaps:

```
sass: function(sassFilename, basename) {
    return gulp.src(paths.sass + sassFilename)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(rename({ basename:basename, suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildCss));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sourcemaps.init()` and `sourcemaps.write()` calls need to "book-end" all the other `.pipe()` stages in your stream. Anything that doesn't happen between `sourcemaps.init()` and `sourcemaps.write()` will not be recorded in your sourcemaps (or might even remove them as is happening in your case).

That means you need to move your `sourcemaps.write()` call to the line after `rename()`:

```
sass: function(sassFilename, basename) {
  return gulp.src(paths.sass + sassFilename)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({ basename:basename, suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildCss));
}
```